# When I do a simulation in LTspice I receive errors

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, capacitor, ltspice

[image]

When I run the simulation I receive errors. I am a beginner in Ltspice and I do not know how to solve this problem.

[image]

I have to draw from 1 to 6

[image]

Comment: You need either the `.inc bc547a.lib` or the `.model BC547A ...` directive, but not both. If you eliminate one of them, do you still get an error?

Comment: Also, each parameter in the `.model` directive is separated from its value with `=`, but you used  `:` for the `mjc` parameter, so that parameter is being ignored.

Comment: @ThePhoton  yes i still get the same error

Comment: @marwa, do you still get it twice (once for BC547A and once for BC557A)?

Comment: @ThePhoton I tried what you said now I get no more errors.
but I have another problem I receive a bode diagram which is not correct I don't know where the problem is

Comment: @ThePhoton  okay thanks .you have an idea why I receive bode diagrams which are not correct

Comment: It's all in the details... check for wiring errors

Comment: @marwa You might not like this, and you may even think it's an ad hominem attack, but it's none of them: if you are, indeed, a beginner (with any tool, not just LTspice) then starting with complex projects is not the way to go. Best look for a tutorial and start from the beginning. If all you want is to see what happens with this schematic, only, then let someone else who knows do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least 4 errors:

- You need either the `.inc bc547a.lib` or the `.model BC547A ...` directive, but not both.
- You need either the `.inc bc557a.lib` or the `.model BC557A ...` directive, but not both.
- Each parameter in the `.model` directive is separated from its value with `=`, but you used `:` for the `mjc` parameter, so that parameter is being ignored.
- There is only one device attached to node `N009`, so no current can flow in or out of that node. This might not be an error, but you should make sure you know where this node is and why you attached only one device to it.

In addition I see an issue that won't cause the simulator to produce errors but probably mean you're not modeling the circuit you intend to:

- C1A and C1B are shorted.

Comment: @marwa, You have wires drawn right through the middle of C1A and C1B. These probably mean no signal reaches the INA128 amplifier, so you get no appreciable output signal. (But your circuit is drawn in a confusing way so I'm not 100% sure what it is supposed to do or what it will actually do)

Comment: The capacitors aren't shorted. The wire overlapping each one stops midway through the symbol; it's a bit hard to see, but the fact that there's only a junction dot on one side is a clue.

Comment: @Hearth thanks a lot .

Comment: @Hearth Now I get no more errors. I think I have to try R6 with ground because I already tried it and it works but I don't know if it's correct.
please I have a question I receive a bode diagram which is not correct I do not know where the problem is

Comment: @marwa What makes you think the Bode plot is wrong? Ask that as a separate question, though; it sounds like your question here has been answered.

Comment: @Hearth okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I'll go through the errors in order.

```
Warning: Multiple definitions of model "bc547a" Type: BJT
```

This warning means that you've defined a `bc547a` device more than once. Here, it looks like you've used a `.inc bc547a.LIB` statement, as well as a `.model bc547a NPN [...]`; assuming that `bc547a.LIB` contains a definition for a device called `bc547a`, you have two definitions of the model in the netlist. Remove one of them (or turn it into a comment if you want to keep it around for later use).

```
Warning: Multiple definitions of model "bc557a" Type: BJT
```

Same story as the last one; remove one of the definitions or turn it into a comment. As an aside, LTspice displays comments in blue text, so it's easy to see at a glance if something is a comment.

```
Warning: Multiple definitions of model "bc547a" Type: BJT
Warning: Multiple definitions of model "bc557a" Type: BJT
```

You get these warnings twice because you get one for each time the model is defined; you'll always see at least two copies of them as far as I know.

```
Error on line 1: .model bc547a npn [...]
                  * Unrecognized parameter "mjc:.33" -- ignored
```

You seem to have used a `:` instead of an `=` for this parameter, which LTspice doesn't know how to interpret, so it's just ignored it.

```
Error on line 1: .model bc557a pnp [...]
                  * Unrecognized parameter "mjc:.33" -- ignored
```

Same problem as above.

```
WARNING: Less than 2 connections to node n009. This node is used by R6.
```

There's a component, R6, that has one of its terminals unconnected. If that's intentional, this isn't a problem. If that's not intentional, you may have misclicked when drawing a wire; go back and double check!

```
Direct Newton iteration failed to find .op point.
```

This just means that the first method LTspice tried to find a DC operating point failed. You can add a statement `.noopiter` to tell it to skip trying this method in the future (which will make the simulation run marginally faster, if you know it's going to fail this attempt anyway).

```
Starting Gmin stepping
[many lines of reports on Gmin and vernier]
Gmin stepping failed
```

This means that LTspice's second method of finding the DC operating point failed. LTspice iterates through three or four different methods to try to find the operating point before running a simulation, unless you specifically instruct it not to and provide the initial conditions yourself. Some of them failing is nothing you need to worry too much about, though it may be a sign that your circuit is difficult to simulate and some tweaks may make it have more success.